# Tkinter dummy window crashes

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm using tkinter to display a simple yesno messagebox in python 3.2.
The code is as follows:

```
x = tkinter.messagebox.askyesno("New Process", "New Process:\n" + e[2:-7] + "\n\nKill?")
```

Althought there is nothing wrong with the code(it functions as I want it to), there is a window in the background that appears and does not respond.

This window will crash after about a few seconds or after killing the host process.

What might cause this?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

It looks like you're not running it as a root window.

```
root = Tk()
app = Frame(root)
app.grid()
my_example = Label(app, "text")
my_example.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

You should put it in a bat file with pause and you'll be able to see the error

Comment: This is not an answer. I appreciate that you do not have enough rep to comment, but please make your answers actual answers so that you can gain rep.

Comment: @R.Murray Sorry. Am I correct in thinking that you are running the frame in a root window, that you've put that in a frame and that the yesno box sits in the frame?

Comment: @R.Murray Lol sorry friend. I'll change the answer to something more appropriate